# Wrong width of environment after includegraphics

Tags: graphics, floats, mdframed

I have created an own environment with the `mdframed` package. My problem is, if I insert a picture in the self defined envrionment, the width of the color box is wrong.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{left=4cm,right=3cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages} 
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=black,bookmarksopen=false,
hypertexnames=TRUE,pdfpagelabels=true]{hyperref}[2011/02/05]

\usepackage{xcolor,bookmark}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{titlepic}
\usepackage{shorttoc}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{type1cm}         
\usepackage{zref-abspage}
\usepackage{makeidx}       
\usepackage{graphicx}        
\usepackage{multicol}        
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{allwithdot} 
\usepackage{thmbox}
\usepackage{shadethm}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usetocstyle{KOMAlike}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\makeindex  

\definecolor{shadethmcolor}{rgb}{.9,.9,.95}%
\definecolor{shadethmcolor2}{rgb}{1,.925,.545}%
\definecolor{aufgaben}{rgb}{0.9333,0.93333,0.933333}%
\definecolor{loesung}{rgb}{0.972,0.93725,0.85098}
\definecolor{textbeispiel}{rgb}{0.86666,0.78431,0.78431}  


\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}
  {\topsep}{\topsep}{}{}%
  {\bfseries}{:}{.5em}{}%

\newtheoremstyle{mystyle2}
  {\topsep}{\topsep}{}{}%
  {\bfseries}{}{.5em}{}%

\theoremstyle{mystyle}

\newmdtheoremenv[hidealllines=true,backgroundcolor=shadethmcolor,skipabove=\topsep,
skipbelow=\topsep]{beispiel}{Beispiel}

\newmdtheoremenv[hidealllines=true,
backgroundcolor=shadethmcolor2,skipabove=\topsep,
skipbelow=\topsep]{formel}{Formel}


\theoremstyle{mystyle2}

\newmdtheoremenv[hidealllines=true,
backgroundcolor=aufgaben,skipabove=\topsep,
skipbelow=\topsep]{aufgabe}{Aufgabe}


\newmdtheoremenv[hidealllines=true,
backgroundcolor=loesung,skipabove=\topsep,
skipbelow=\topsep]{loesung}{L\"osung}


\begin{document}
\begin{loesung}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{histloesungzeichnung.png}\\
c)\\
Here comes a lot of text which describes different things, but this complete area should have the same color background width as the solution below! : $\bar{x}=\frac{1}{99}(18*1.5+20*3.5+25*5+22*7+14*9)$
\end{loesung}
\begin{loesung}
here comes the next solution with the correct width of the color background box!
\end{looesung}
\end{document}
```

How can I make the color box has the same width?

Also a general question: If I try to include a float figure, it does not work. It seems to me, that this is in general not possible, to include a float `figure` in the self defined environment `loesung`. Also a `table` is not possible (but `tabular`). Any ideas on this? The error message if I use figures in the `loesung` environment is `Float(s) lost`.

I am writing on a larger document, so I have this problem several times and it really rips me of. I solved the other problems with just using `tabular`, but here in this case, I really need the picture there to be included.

Thanks a lot!

I attached a screenshot of my problem (I changed the text, so you can better understand the problem, the changing of the text does not matter), I have no account so I have to give you the screenshot:

[image: http://tinypic.com/r/33wbhb6/6]

Comment: Your example code doesn't compile; the `thmbox` and `amsthm` packages conflict; also, there's a typo in `\end{looesung}` (it should be `\end{loesung}`).

Comment: `floats` can not go in boxes, but boxes can go in `floats`

Comment: @GonzaloMedina it was in response to, 'Also a general question'...

Comment: well, first of all thanks a lot, but if I change it to \textwidth it is getting a bit more width but it is still not correct! and to the general question: What does that mean "boxes can go in floats", how can I add a figure in a loesung environment?

Answer (score 1):

In the `\includegraphics` instruction, don't use `[scale=0.5]`; instead, use `[width=\textwidth]`.

Separately, two humble requests: 1. When posting a minimum working example, **please** eliminate all typos (see: `\end{looesung}`); do note the word "working" in the term "minimum working example". 2. Please also avoid loading any and all packages in the MWE that are aren't strictly needed to illustrate and/or replicate the problem at hand.